# How do I get array value from xml data returned by C# webservice using Phonegap JQuery?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web-services, cordova

I have webservice developed in .net which returns output in array string like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<string>New Orleans, Louisiana</string>
<string>New York, New York</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

How do i parse this xml in my javascript?

Comment: refer this link. [You can parse the xml using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: thanks for the help but its not working.

Comment: Have a look to this JSFiddle..
I have added a working example for you here..
It is working as expected..
http://jsfiddle.net/XQtjx/

Comment: Is it working correct? Please mark as correct answer if you got the solution form the jsfiddle i provided

Comment: its working correct. thanks.